# Settings for column labels in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggally

I recently started working with ggplot2 and GGally and wanted to create a matrix of scatter plots for visualizing the correlation using the function ggpairs.

The output looks quite nice using:

```
ggpairs(df, axisLabels="none")
```

All I want to change is the font for the column labels, so that one can easier read the names of my variables. It should be  **bold** and maybe a little bit bigger.
But unless I missed something in the documentation, there doesn't seem to any direct way to access these settings.

Is there maybe a known workaround?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Does `ggpairs(iris, axisLabels="none") + theme_bw(base_size = 15)` do some of what you want?

Comment: Yes! I added "+theme_gray(base_size =16, base_family = "bold")" and now it looks like I want it.Thank you.